# Why would a web app's Solr search engine return ‘Java Spring’ results when searched for ‘Spring Fertility’? How can one fix this?

Tags: java, search, solr, lucene, full-text-search

Actually we don't have the Solr or Lucene engine right now for this web app. We noticed following these two issues in a web app. How should one fix this?

1) When user searches with the term "Java Spring", the results shown include "Spring fertility" etc.? I guess right now the search engine running behind web app does text based/semantic search. 
How to enable context based search (I came up with the term context based search on the fly, not sure if ones exists), when user searches for a technical term "java Spring" it doesn't include results like "spring season" or "iron spring".

2) Second issue, I noticed is, if we search for "TeslaLLC" no results are returned. But if we modify the search term as "Tesla LLC" (with the space) it returns values. How should one fix this? (It looks like the value they fed into the system was "Tesla LLC" (with space). But a user can type with or without spaces and in my opinion, the search engine should handle both.

We knew that the technology used is Solr and Lucene. 
So, if you could advise based on the technology, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

It all depends on how you index the fields. What field types are used for a field.
Does the fields type have different analysers at index time and query etc.
A field type consist of or build of tokenizer, filters etc.

There are many tokenizers and filters made available in order to build a custom field type.
There are some default field type provided in the schema.xml file. 
You can apply those to your fields and examine how the data is indexed(how the tokens are created) at query time and index time.

This can be examined or analysed with the help of solr admin page.

Example of a custom field type.

```
<fieldType name="Custom_text" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Input to solr field : `"Please, email john.doe@foo.com by 03-09, re: m37-xq."`

Output of the solr field : `"please", "email", "john.doe", "foo.com", "by", "03", "09", "re", "m37", "xq"`

Now coming back to your question.

1. It looks like you want exact match. You can use string type for your field instead of text. If you use text then you use keywordtokenizer which will not create any tokens of your text. It will stored/indexed as it is. Hence you will get exact match.
2. In this case the applied field type might have created the tokens like "Tesla LLC" or "Tesla", "LLC" in solr. Here as well it all depends on the tokenizers and fiters been used for the same field type. So it will not match you string of ""TeslaLLC"" as solr does not find the tokens for the same string.

Many things are possible with solr. But all you need to understand the field, field type, tokenizers, filters, analysers at index time and query time(you can keep the same analyser at query and index time or different as well , depends on the your requirement)

[Link for tokenisers, filters](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/understanding-analyzers-tokenizers-and-filters.html)

Comment: For the first case defining the `mm` clause to be 100% would probably be better, as they're looking for all the terms of their query to match.

Comment: For the second question -- I would suggest to look into Solr's synonyms https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/filter-descriptions.html#filter-descriptions